# Django: Having unique extension numbers associated with a client, but same extension number associated with another client

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm working on a project where I have models: Client, User, and Extensions, just to make this simple.
A User has to be associated with one Client in order to have an Extension number.
A User can have extensions, say, 100 and 101.
Another User, associated with another Client, can have the same extensions 100 and 101.
So, Extensions is not unique in my database so it's allowing a User to have two identical extension numbers when I add it in the Administration, which is wrong. How can check that the extension number to be added is not contained in this user already?

```
class Extension(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=u"User")
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=True)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=False)
    kind = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=KIND_CHOICES,default=KIND_UNKNOWN)
```

The User class is the default Django class.

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(u"Nome", max_length=64)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    last_inbound_call  = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    last_outbound_call = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=16)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Meta.unique_together`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) on `user` and `number` in `Extension`.

```
class Extension(...):
   ...
  class Meta:
    unique_together = (('user', 'number'),)
```

Comment: Alright, I was on the right track. Need to try it now. Thank you.

Comment: It works, but there can be many users under the same client. These users under the same client cannot have the same extension number. Do I have to create another foreign key in Extension to Client and include 'client' in unique_together?

Comment: What relation exists between `Client` and `User`?